# Finding process id of a Node.js server in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

To find a process id of a node.js server in unix, we use below code:

```
if (process.getgid) {
   console.log('Current gid: ' + process.getgid());
}
```

So I get output as `1888` in *nix OS, but when I execute same in Windows OS, I am getting output as `undefined` also as per node.js docs they have explicitly mentioned this method won't work in windows.

So my question, is there anyway I can get process id in windows os? I tried to execute `taskkill /f /im node.exe` but it kills all node processes, but I want to kill only particualr process. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

on windows `process.pid` works for me.

regarding the docs, [getgid](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_getgid) is not returning the Process ID, rather the  *group identity of the process*, to get the process id use [pid](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_pid)

To kill the process use:

```
taskkill /f /pid processID
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what I was looking for, I will try with different versions (xp, 7, 32bit, 64bit) and will update you.

Comment: great, I tested it on win7 64bit.

Comment: is there any difference between process.getgid and process.pid if you're aware? Doc mentions no information about the same :)

Comment: I found this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group), I think it would explain better what is the difference, than me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [tasklist](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tasklist.mspx?mfr=true) to find the correct ID...

You can then use taskkill when you sort through the correct id to kill that particular one. Not entirely sure if it'd work in node. But it's something that'd work on the CMD.

Comment: tasklist is of no help. It shows the parent node.exe and the child node.exe but there is no help there to know which one to kill.